# angular-loading-bar doesn't work as expected with Ionic framework (1)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar).

It is supposed the loading bar should be shown for any XHR call. But when I try to make it run with Ionic it doesn't work until I run it manually.

Anyone managed to make it work as expected?
Any tip?

Thanks

Comment: can you show working demo of your code?

Comment: Hello @PareshGami. Thanks for your comment. This question is more about making some components work together than concrete code. Do you know something about the component I'm talking about? Did you use it in a Ionic project? Did you have any issue to work automatically following the installation/usage documentation in github?